# Jupyter download as PDF via LaTeX cutting off code at margins

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyter

New to Jupyter Notebook and trying to download the .ipynb file as a PDF via LaTex.  I am trying to use pre-made templates so that the code in the cells aren't getting cut off at the margins when it converts to a PDF file.  So far, I have tried two solutions (listed below) but running into errors, maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Attempted Solution #1:
I followed the README in a pre-made template here: https://github.com/t-makaro/nb_pdf_template
Then in Jupyter Notebook: File > Download As > PDF via LaTex and get this error, see screenshot below.  Am I placing the template files in the wrong folder and thus Jupyter Notebook is somehow not picking it up?

[image]

Attempted Solution #2:
I followed the steps in this guy's solution also:
https://www.markus-beuckelmann.de/blog/customizing-nbconvert-pdf.html
but then I get some error: ! LaTeX Error: File `tcolorbox.sty' not found.

Answer (score 1):

I tried replicating the error following the steps at the GitHub [linked](https://github.com/t-makaro/nb_pdf_template) on a Google Colab notebook. I've added the installation of [additional libraries](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex) that are needed by `nbconvert` in order to unlock further capabilities.

```
!pip install nb_pdf_template

!python -m nb_pdf_template.install

!apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-plain-generic

!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf ../testing.ipynb --template classic
```

This works without any problems on my end.

Comment: Hello, I failed to mention this part also.  I had added that line to both files jupyter_nbconvert_config.py and also jupyter_notebook_config.py.  Just tried running the command line given and getting this error:   ...
ValueError: Unsupported mimetype 'application/pdf' for template 'classic', mimetypes supported are:
        text/html

Comment: It seems it doesn't support application/pdf and only text/html.  I read a bit further and it seems I had to download pandoc in order to make the switch to application/pdf.  Now I've installed pandoc and still not working.  Is there some sort of configuration I have to setup with pandoc to link to the LaTex?

Comment: If you haven't already it might be worth try installing this TeX additional packages: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex

Comment: Installing pandoc has fixed the error " ValueError: Unsupported mimetype 'application/pdf'..."? If so, you say that it is still not working by executing the instruction from the command line. What is the error in this case?

Comment: Installing pandoc does not fix the error " ValueError: Unsupported mimetype 'application/pdf'.  I thought that installing pandoc would fix this error but it seems it did not.  I was not sure if there is some missing configuration I have to do even after installing pandoc to fix this error?

Comment: I think pandoc does not requires further configurations. I've updated the answer with steps I followed to get it working

Comment: It seems I already have the MikTex installed because in the installation prompt it says that the directory is not empty.  Let me go through your updated steps now.  Hopefully this will fix the issue!